# How to set up profiles and sessions in Firebase and Ionic using Facebook Auth

Tags: facebook, session, facebook-graph-api, ionic-framework, firebase-authentication

I am very new to Firebase and struggling to set up a system where a user logs in via Facebook, and his/her profile picture is saved in a database.

I have a users and also a uids array in Firebase. What I want the flow to be is:

1. Login via Facebook
2. Store some memory of the user so they don't have to login again on the app, or perhaps store into the uids and users array
3. Get the existing name, location to fill into a profile section of the app
4. Update any of these to then fill into the Firebase users database, as well as add new fields e.g. location

Here is my current setup:

Login Controller:

```
.controller('LoginCtrl', ['Auth', '$state', '$location', '$scope', '$rootScope', '$firebaseAuth', '$window',
        function (Auth, $state, $location, $scope, $rootScope, $firebaseAuth, $window) {
            // check session
            //$rootScope.checkSession;
            // Create a callback to handle the result of the authentication

            $scope.user = {
                email: this.email,
                password: this.password
            };

            $scope.validateUser = function (user) {

                $rootScope.show('Please wait.. Authenticating');
                console.log('Please wait.. Authenticating');

                var email = this.user.email;
                var password = this.user.password;

                /* Check user fields*/
                if (!email || !password) {
                    $rootScope.hide();
                    $rootScope.notify('Error', 'Email or Password is incorrect!');
                    return;
                }

                /* All good, let's authentify */
                Auth.$authWithPassword({
                    email: email,
                    password: password
                }).then(function (authData) {
                    console.log(authData);
                    //$rootScope.userEmail = user.email;
                    $window.location.href = ('#/app/meals');
                    $rootScope.hide();
                }).catch(function (error) {
                    console.log("Login Failed!", error);
                    if (error.code == 'INVALID_EMAIL') {
                        $rootScope.notify('Invalid Email Address');
                    }
                    else if (error.code == 'INVALID_PASSWORD') {
                        $rootScope.notify('Invalid Password');
                    }
                    else if (error.code == 'INVALID_USER') {
                        $rootScope.notify('Invalid User');
                    }
                    else {
                        $rootScope.notify('Oops something went wrong. Please try again later');
                    }
                    $rootScope.hide();
                    //$rootScope.notify('Error', 'Email or Password is incorrect!');
                });
            };

         $scope.loginWithGoogle = function () {
            Auth.$authWithOAuthPopup('google')
                .then(function (authData) {
                    $state.go($location.path('app/meals'));
                });
        };

        $scope.loginWithFacebook = function () {

            Auth.$authWithOAuthPopup('facebook')
                .then(function (authData) {
                    console.log(authData);
                    $state.go($location.path('app/meals'));
                })
                .catch(function(error){
                    if (error.code === "TRANSPORT_UNAVAILABLE") {
                        Auth.$authWithOAuthRedirect("facebook").then(function (authData) {
                            // User successfully logged in. We can log to the console
                            // since we’re using a popup here
                            console.log(authData);
                            $state.go($location.path('app/meals'));
                        });
                    } else {
                        // Another error occurred
                        console.log(error);
                    }

                });

        };

        }
    ])
```

Key functions like get session I want in `$rootScope`:

```
.run(function ($ionicPlatform, $rootScope, $firebaseAuth, $firebase, $window, $ionicLoading) {
        $ionicPlatform.ready(function () {
            // Hide the accessory bar by default (remove this to show the accessory bar above the keyboard
            // for form inputs)
            if (window.cordova && window.cordova.plugins.Keyboard) {
                cordova.plugins.Keyboard.hideKeyboardAccessoryBar(true);
                cordova.plugins.Keyboard.disableScroll(true);

            }
            if (window.StatusBar) {
                // org.apache.cordova.statusbar required
                StatusBar.styleDefault();
            }

            $rootScope.userEmail = null;
            $rootScope.baseUrl = 'https://[myappurl.firebaseio.com/';
            var authRef = new Firebase($rootScope.baseUrl);
            $rootScope.auth = $firebaseAuth(authRef);
            $rootScope.authData = authRef.getAuth();

            $rootScope.show = function(text) {
                $rootScope.loading = $ionicLoading.show({
                    content: text ? text : 'Loading..',
                    animation: 'fade-in',
                    showBackdrop: true,
                    maxWidth: 200,
                    showDelay: 0
                });
            };

            $rootScope.hide = function() {
                $ionicLoading.hide();
            };

            $rootScope.notify = function(text) {
                $rootScope.show(text);
                $window.setTimeout(function() {
                    $rootScope.hide();
                }, 1999);
            };

            $rootScope.logout = function() {
                authRef.unauth();
                $rootScope.authDataCallBack;
            };

            $rootScope.checkSession = function() {
                if ($rootScope.authData) {
                    console.log("User " + authData.uid + " is logged in with " + authData.provider);
                    $rootScope.userEmail = user.email;
                    $window.location.href = ('#/app/meals');
                } else {
                    console.log("No session so logout");
                    $rootScope.userEmail = null;
                    $window.location.href = '#/auth/signin';
                }
            }

            $rootScope.authDataCallBack = function(authData) {
                if ($rootScope.authData) {
                    console.log("User " + authData.uid + " is logged in with " + authData.provider);
                } else {
                    console.log("User is logged out");
                    $window.location.href = '#/auth/signin';
                }
            };

        });
    })
```

The profile page:

```
<ion-view view-title="Profile">
    <ion-content class="has-header">
        <div class="list card">
            <div class="item">
                <h2>{{user.name}}</h2>
                <p>{{user.city}}</p>
            </div>
            <!--https://github.com/israelidanny/ion-profile-picture-->
            <!--<div class="item item-body">-->
                <!--<img src="http://graph.facebook.com/{{user.id}}/picture?width=270&height=270"/>-->
            <!--</div>-->
        </div>
    </ion-content>
</ion-view>
```

Auth factory:

```
app.factory('Auth', ['rootRef', '$firebaseAuth', function (rootRef, $firebaseAuth) {
    return $firebaseAuth(rootRef);
}]);
```

If it helps, here is my `SignUpCtrl` which pushes items into the users array and also stores an array of uids of users already set up in the app.

```
.controller('SignUpCtrl', [
        '$scope', '$rootScope', '$firebaseAuth', '$window', 'Auth',
        function ($scope, $rootScope, $firebaseAuth, $window, Auth) {

            $scope.user = {
                firstname: this.firstname,
                lastname: this.lastname,
                email: "",
                password: ""
            };
            $scope.createUser = function () {
                var firstname = this.user.firstname;
                var lastname = this.user.lastname;
                var email = this.user.email;
                var password = this.user.password;



                if (!email || !password) {
                    $rootScope.notify("Please enter valid credentials");
                    return false;
                }

                $rootScope.show('Please wait.. Registering');
                $rootScope.auth.$createUser(
                    {email: email, password: password})
                    .then(function (user) {
                        console.log('user is created');
                        $rootScope.hide();
                        $rootScope.userEmail = user.email;
                        var usersRef = new Firebase('https://foodsharingapp.firebaseio.com/users');
                        var keyRef = usersRef.push({
                            'uid': user.uid,
                            'email': email,
                            'firstname': firstname,
                            'lastname': lastname
                        });
                        var uidRef = new Firebase('https://[myapp].firebaseio.com/uids/' + user.uid + '/' + keyRef.key());
                        uidRef.set({'registered': true});
                        $window.location.href = ('#/app/meals');
                    }, function (error) {
                        console.log('error unfortunately');
                        $rootScope.hide();
                        if (error.code == 'INVALID_EMAIL') {
                            console.log('invalid email');
                            $rootScope.notify('Invalid Email Address');
                        }
                        else if (error.code == 'EMAIL_TAKEN') {
                            console.log('email taken');
                            $rootScope.notify('Email Address already taken');
                        }
                        else {
                            console.log('not sure what happened');
                            $rootScope.notify('Oops something went wrong. Please try again later');
                        }
                    });

            }
```

**Questions:**

1. I want to call `$rootScope.authDataCallBack(authData)` on any controller to get the name and any details of the user_id logged in, however this is not working. Am I thinking about this right? How can I use my $rootScope functions as ways to obtain global information?
2. When I log in I see the Facebook object appearing fine, should I use the Facebook ID as a uid to store in my array?
3. On any view, how can I use the session uid or authData to then match against my list of users in the user array and pull out more detailed user info? Is there some pseudocode I can use and would this be in every function in my controller, or would it be split between factory and controller?

Comment: Try reducing the scope of your question so that it may be easier for the community to offer help.

Comment: See specific questions - I want to use `$rootScope with the authData` on any page (beyond the login page) to know who is logged in but I don't seem to be able to use this. I also want to know what code to write to match this to a set of object in a Firebase array and get the Firebase object details (location, preferences etc). Hope this is clearer!

Comment: I have realised I can use `Auth.$getAuth());` to get the details of the authenticated user. Now how do I used rootScope?